# How to close database connection in nestjs service?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, nestjs

In my database module I'm creating a connection to my database. With this setup I do get the error

**A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --runInBand --detectOpenHandles to find leaks.**

in my e2e tests.

I think I have to close the connection. But how do I run `client.close` in the `onModuleDestroy()` in my Databasemodule?

**database.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { MongoClient, Db, Logger } from 'mongodb'

@Module({
    providers: [
        {
            provide: 'DATABASE_CONNECTION',
            useFactory: async (): Promise<Db> => {
                const mongo = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
                const database = 'testing'

                try {
                    Logger.setLevel('debug')

                    const client = await MongoClient.connect(mongo, {
                        useNewUrlParser: true,
                        useUnifiedTopology: true,
                    });

                    const db = client.db(database)
                    return db
                } catch (error) {
                    throw error
                }
            }
        },
        {
            provide: 'DATABASE_CLIENT',
            useFactory: () => true // how do I get client of the above provider?
        }
    ],
    exports: ['DATABASE_CONNECTION', 'DATABASE_CLIENT']
})

export class DatabaseModule {
    constructor(
        @Inject('DATABASE_CLIENT')
        private client: Db
    ) {}

    async onModuleDestroy() {
        console.log(this.client);
        // await this.client.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: Very likely yes, that's the problem. Do a cleanup in a hook, https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events . onModuleDestroy, I guess.

Comment: @EstusFlask But how can I close the client as the database module is returning the `db` instead of `client`? Please have a look at the updated post regarding the service code.

Comment: This needs to be done in db service or module, not in a consumer, it's module's responsibility to clean up after itself. And yes, you need to keep a reference to `client` for this. Probably with a separate provider, `{ provide: 'DATABASE_CLIENT' useFactory: () => ({ client: null }) }`. Inject it to DATABASE_CONNECTION to assign client property, and to DatabaseModule to access it in onModuleDestroy. I'm not sure what's the best way to do this in Nest, would be easier if db service were a class.

Comment: What do you mean by `inject it to DATABASE_CONNECTION? Could you please post an example with the db service as a class?

Comment: I mean to use DI to inject client service into connection factory. I posted the code. I cannot confirm if it's workable but I'd expect it to be done this way, more or less.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Opened database connection is a common cause for this problem. A module needs to clean up after itself, this especially applies to testing where a module can be instantiated multiple times.

`client` reference needs to be preserved for a cleanup. This could be done with single class service:

```
@Injectable()
class DatabaseConnection {
  async onModuleInit() {
    // ...same as DATABASE_CONNECTION factory
    this.client = client;
    this.db = client.db(database);
  }
  async onModuleDestroy() {
    await this.client.close()
  } 
}
```

Or with two factory providers, one of which keeps a reference to `client`:

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'DATABASE_CLIENT',
      useFactory: () => ({ client: null })
    },
    {
      provide: 'DATABASE_CONNECTION',
      inject: ['DATABASE_CLIENT'],
      useFactory: async (dbClient) => {
        ...
        dbClient.client = client
        const db = client.db(database)
        return db;
      }
    }
  ]
  ...
})
export class DatabaseModule {
  constructor(@Inject('DATABASE_CLIENT') private dbClient) {}

  async onModuleDestroy() {
    await this.dbClient.client.close()
  } 
}
```

Comment: It needs to be `await this.dbClient.client.close()` because dbClient has the object client. You have to use an object for the first provider?

Comment: I was in the middle of writing a comment. Did it work for you in the end? I expect two solutions to be equivalent and onModuleDestroy to be called in both cases. Yes, that's a typo, it should have `client` property. Yes, it's necessary to have an object to pass a reference to `client`, that's a popular recipe in JS.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is working perfectly. Sorry, for the deleted comment. But it was just the missing property, which I didn't recognize first.

Comment: If you can not decide which method to use this warning from nestjs documentation can be a guide "WARNING
If your class doesn't extend another provider, you should always prefer using constructor-based injection."